# Merging data from multiple Rails tables in a view

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am making a game in Rails where there are multiple games each day at different times. In my Pages Controller, I am showing users what the next four available games are:

```
  @quizzes = Quiz.where("game_start >= ?", Time.now).order(game_start: :asc).limit(4)
```

The `Quiz` model has a `game_start` column, so this is easy.

I would like to have a second table for the user showing what the next games are that *they have registered for*. So this will need to be specific to the `current_user`, and it will need to check a `Reservation` table used to indicate if a user has already registered for the game.

This is where it gets tricky. Based on the best practice to use specific, smaller models, the table for `Reservation` is the following:

```
 class CreateReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :reservations do |t|
       t.integer :user_id
       t.string :category
  t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

So in my controller, if I were to use:

```
 @reservations = Reservation.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

It will return the `category` name of games a user has registered for. This isn't very useful to the user though. Information like `game_start` (when a game begins) is located in the `Quiz` model, referenced above.

Let's say I format this in the view as a table. One column is using `@reservations` to query which `category` games have been signed up for (like "history" and "sports"). Could I also query the `@quizzes` model to - in the table table - show corresponding `game_start` times?

In short, I want the controller to 1) show the user the games they have signed up for (working) and 2) based on the `category` of those games, query the `Quiz` table and also show the `game_start` times.

Is that possible?

Additional, For Reference: `Quiz` Table:

```
class CreateQuizzes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quizzes do |t|
      t.string :category
      t.datetime :game_start
      t.integer :entry
      t.timestamps
    end
```

Comment: it is simple as you are storing the resultant collection in different objects.

Comment: Good to hear. Let's say I added `@quizzes` in the controller. What would I need to do in the view to ensure the `game_start` for the category `history` matches to the corresponding object in the `Reservation` table for `history`? Could I use `.where` to connect the categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the optimal strategy, but I figured out a way to accomplish my core goal: query the `Reservation` table for games with an existing reservation and then show the `game_start` time from the separate `Quiz` table in the view.

In my controller, I just used an `and` statement:

```
  @reservations = Reservation.where(user_id: current_user.id) && Quiz.where("game_start > ?", Time.now)
```

Then in my index file, I could call data from both tables successfully, and it looks like it is working:

```
<% @reservations.each do |reservation| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= reservation.category %></td>
      <td><%= reservation.game_start %></td>
          <% end %>
```

Simple enough. Let me know if there is a better approach.